# Move resource into the the root folder with Google Docs List API

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to move a Resource into the root folder of a user's Docs account using the Google Docs List API (Python SDK).

The client.move_resource method requires a gdata.docs.data.Resource as the target collection, but I can't figure out how to get the Resource entry for the root folder, or if that's even possible. The API docs say

> When getting entries back from API feeds, you will never find a resource entry with a resource ID of folder:root because the root collection does not have its own entry.

If I try to use move_resource(entry=entry, collection=None, keep_in_collections=False) I end up with the Resource not in anything, including the root folder, such that if I query the contents of the root folder, I don't get that Resource in the response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, my solution for Obj-C framework was to find some GTLDriveFile with root parent ref and set it to file which i want move to root.